# How to regex numerical interval from a string in Hive

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I have a column with item descriptions. For example like this:

```
1 Frozen Pacific Whiting Fillets, Skin-on, Value Bag, 4 lbs.
2 Raised Fresh Atlantic Salmon Fillet, 1.5-2.5 lbs
```

I want to extract 1.5-2.5 from line 2. I dont want to just extract numbers but a numerical range.

I tried using the below expression but it's not working:

```
regex_Extract(column,(.*?)[0-9]\\.[0-9](-)[0-9]\\.[0-9],0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Hive,regexp groups start from 1, not 0.

```
regexp_extract(col,'([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+-[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+)',1)
```

If the interval value has to be preceded and succeeded by a whitespace, use

```
regexp_extract(col,'(^|\\s)([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+-[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+)(\\s|$)',2)
```

This solution assumes there is only one interval value in the string.

- `(^|\\s)` - matches whitespace or beginning of the string
- `([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+-[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+)` - matches digit(s), followed by an optional `.`, followed by digit(s), followed by a `-`, followed by digit(s), followed by an optional `.`, followed by digit(s)
- `(\\s|$)` - matches the whitespace or end of the string